# Python class initialization for newbie

Tags: python

First I make a python file clss.py

```py
class A:

    def __init__(self, a):
        A.a = a


class B(A):

    def __init__(self, b, c):
        B.b = b
        if c:
            B.c = c
        else:
            B.c = '0'


def get_list(csv_filename):
    test_list = []
    with open(csv_filename) as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
        next(reader)
        try:
            for row in reader:
                test_list.append(B(row[0], row[1], row[2]))
        except:
            pass
    return test_list
```

Then I read a csv file from prog.py where some 'None' values exists and a lot of normal values:

```
from clss.py import *

test = get_list('my_file.csv')
for i in test:
    print(i.c)
```

And it gives me all '0'

Comment: Why are you using `B.c`? *There is only one of those*.

Comment: And actually, I'm surprised you are getting any output. You should always fail here: `test_list.append(B(row[0], row[1], row[2]))` because the `B` constructor only takes two arguments, but you are passing 3. You really should do something like `try: ... except: pass`.

Comment: I strongly suspect that when you write `A.a = a`, you *really* mean `self.a = a`. Same goes for instances of `B.b` and `B.c`.

Comment: Yep guys you are right. I've missed 'a' while copying the code here. In my initial code 'a' is present in class 'B'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `B.c = '0'`, you set the variable ***at the class level***, so all your objects will have the same value.

Replace all `B.` with `self.` in your class `B`. The same for class `A` with `A.`.